# how to disable specific buttons with discord.py bot

Tags: python, button, discord, discord.py, pokeapi

I would like to know if there is a way for me to disable a button after I click on another one. Example:

[image]

when I click on the stats button, I need the shiny button to be disabled!

I did something similar, however for the same button I clicked:

[image]

I used the `button.disabled = True` and it worked, but to disable another button also by clicking on the stats button, I couldn't! Can you help?

Comment: Can you provide at the very least your view/button code? It is possible to do what you're asking but ideally, seeing your code and what you've tried would help us help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming you have a `View` class that inherits from [`discord.ui.View`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#view) and your [buttons](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#id1) are defined like the following. We can use the `self` property on the `View` class to get the view's children (ie; buttons, selects, etc) and then iterate over them and looking for buttons that have the *shiny* label.

```py
class View(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label="shiny")
    async def shiny_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        pass

    @discord.ui.button(label="stats")
    async def stats_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        # defer whilst we work out stats stuff
        await interaction.response.defer()

        message = interaction.message

        # find the shiny button and disable it
        # keep a reference to the right button in case we want to enable it later
        shiny_button = None
        for child in self.children:
            if type(child) == discord.ui.Button and child.label == "shiny":
                shiny_button = child
                child.disabled = True
                break

        # update the view in discord
        await interaction.message.edit(content=message.content, view=self)

        # do the rest of what the `stats` button should do

        # actually send followup message to user
        await interaction.followup.send("stats")

        # if we wanted to re-enable the other button we can do it here
        # commented out
        # shiny_button.disabled = False
        # await interaction.message.edit(content=message.content, view=self)


    @discord.ui.button(label="back")
    async def back_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        pass
```

The example is quite simple; we defer to stop discord complaining we didn't respond, then we do what I said and then edit the message immediately to disable the `shiny` button to prevent anyone from pressing it. Then you can do your logic. then we can send our followup message to let the user know we did what we should have done. And then, *optionally*, we re-enable the button again.