# Discord.py - Clicking button in a view can't access the interaction's message

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to follow this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75396860. I would have commented on it to get clarity, but SO won't allow me to.

I'm just trying to accomplish one simple thing: when `Button 1` is pressed, enable `Button 2`

**View Class**

```py
import discord

class Signup(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label="Button 1")
    async def one_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()

        for child in self.children:
            if type(child) == discord.ui.Button and child.label == "Button 2":
                child.disabled = False
                await interaction.message.edit(view=self)

        await interaction.followup.send("Button 1 Pressed, Button 2 Enabled")

    @discord.ui.button(label="Button 2", disabled=True)
    async def two_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        pass
```

I initially send the message like this:

```py
await channel.send(content="Click Button 1 to get Button 2!", view=Signup())
```

With this code, I receive the following error when it gets to `interaction.response.defer()`:

```
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'
```

It seems like the `Interaction` is always `type` `discord.Button` for me, which doesn't have `response` or `message` as attributes. The same code appears to work for others, though, as this SO thread is not the only place that I've seen the same logic being used. I'm not quite sure where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was in the answer at the other SO thread. The arguments were out of order in the callback function.

I had:

```py
async def one_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
```

Should be:

```py
async def one_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
```

The docs state the order here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.button

> The function being decorated should have three parameters, `self` representing the `discord.ui.View`, the `discord.Interaction` you receive and the `discord.ui.Button` being pressed.

Thanks to the discord.py Discord for saving me from my self!